# Remove double quote from an api using React js

Tags: node.js, api, reactjs

I want to remove de double quote from API result. This is the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlVFw.jpg)

```
componentDidMount() {
     fetch('/todo/2')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) =>{
      this.setState({
        message: responseJson.data.Publicacion
      });
    })
  }
```

Here is where I'm printing the result in react js:

```
<div className="card-container">
     <div className="card">
          <img className="avatar" src={avatar} alt="" />
          <div className="name">Peter Stark</div>
          <div className="date">A las 4:56 p.m. </div>

          <p className="card">
            {JSON.stringify(this.state.message)}
          </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you stringify it?

Comment: No need to stringify, using `<p>{this.state.message}</p>` should be sufficient.

Comment: It works thank you